# iTextSharp issues wherein null reference exception

Tags: itext

I am using iTextSharp with C# to fill an editable PDF. Everything was working fine, but suddenly I am getting an error on the PdfStamper line.

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(File.ReadAllBytes(pdfTemplatePath));
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write));
AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
```

The error is

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=itextsharp
  StackTrace:
   at iTextSharp.text.Version.GetInstance()
```

I have checked the file paths and everything - that is all correct. I have also made sure there are no permission issues.

Can someone please let me what might be causing this to throw a null reference exception.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If *suddenly* the behavior of coffee changes, you should first of all ask yourself whether something happened to its installation or the installation of its dependencies. If you think that can't have happened, then wonder whether there was a change in the program inputs, I.e. there pdfs. You might want to share typical old and current input pdfs for analysis.

Comment: No it's not working. Cant understand but for some reason, the filestream reader is having timeout issues.

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace, not merely the `iTextSharp.text.Version.GetInstance()` line?

Comment: @user1144596, I'm wondering if the issue might be an update the Adobe Acrobat reader? A colleague and I are working on a new app. It wasn't like yours because we added the capability to generate PDFs just this week. Anyway, our version of Adobe Acrobat was upgraded over the Christmas/New Years. The code my colleague used has been used in other apps people here have written, so we know it worked.

Comment: Ever get this figured out? Spent all day on this and never could get past this bug.